# issue with angular http services url not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I am trying to post data to api servers but it keeps giving me 404. I tried it in postman and it works fine. I am using JSONP to post data because of cross domain issue
here is what the console shows

```
GET http://myapi.com/registrations.json 404 (Not Found) angular.js:8227

undefined 0 function (name) {
    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

    if (name) {
      return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
    }

    return headersObj;
  } 
Object {method: "JSONP", transformRequest: Array[1], transformResponse: Array[1], url: "http://shipit-integration.herokuapp.com/registrations.json", data: Object…}
data: Object
registration: Object
email: "email@example.com"
password: "pass1234"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
headers: Object
Accept: "application/json"
Content-Type: "application/json"
__proto__: Object
method: "JSONP"
transformRequest: Array[1]
transformResponse: Array[1]
url: "http://myapi.com/registrations.json"
__proto__: Object
```

here is my code

```
    var data = {
        "registration": {
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "password": "pass1234"
        }
    };

    var headers =  {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    };

    $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: 'http://myapi.com/registrations.json',
        data: data,
        headers: headers
    }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data, status, headers, config);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data, status, headers, config);
        });
}
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass `data` and `headers`. The parameters for a `jsonp` request are `url` and `config`. It doesn't accept `data` (unlike other types of requests) and `headers` are returned from the server, you don't send them to it. I suggest you use a `post` request and return the json string (that's when you use a header).

I suggest you read [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

That is apart from making sure the server gets your request and sends the response properly. Not sure where you are trying to send a request to, but `http://myapi.com/registrations.json` doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

I had to make sure I am allowing cross domain on server. Appearently cross domian testings work on postman but not when you actually try.